# Why does slick slider not work with tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slick.js

I used slick slider in tabs. In first tab slides are work good. But when we clicked on second tab - slider disappears.

https://codepen.io/malinosky/pen/jvgqxO?editors=1010

I used

```
$('.js-photo').slick("setPosition", 0);
$('.js-presentation').slick("setPosition", 0);
```

But that's don't work for me. What's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when the slider is hidden, it has a height of 0.

So you should refresh the positioning of slick when the slider is visible:

```
target.fadeIn("200", function() {
    $('.js-photo').slick("setPosition", 0);
});
```

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jvgVqR

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution through CSS and it's working well at mine.

You could set the not-active tabs to

```
overflow-y: hidden
height: 0
```

instead of the classic

```
display:none
```

Reference link :
https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/341

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set onClick function on the tabs (by class) or one tab (by id) like this

```
$("#tab1").click(function(){
    $('.carousel-1').slick('refresh');
});
```

be careful on the tab and tab-pane

reference [Github](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/3366#issuecomment-372283200)

Answer (score 0):

The codepen demo missed an initial `setPosition` of original codes.

I've also forked a codepen demo:
https://codepen.io/RobJS/pen/zJgojN?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

```
  autoplay: false,
  autoplaySpeed: 2000,
  fade: true,
  arrows: false,
  **lazyLoad:'ondemand'**
```

Use `lazyload` and wait 2 seconds after clicking (codepen takes this time to update).